# How to click a button which is not a form submit button during a functional test

Tags: symfony, functional-testing, phpunit

During a functional test i need to click a button to make an ajax request.
When browsing the symfony testing docs, i realized that you could whether click :

- a Link
  or
- a form's submit button

My button has the following id = "js-scroll-down"

When i try this:

```
  $btn = $crawler->filter('#js-scroll-down')->eq(0)->link();
  $crawler = $client->click($btn);
```

I get the following error:
LogicException: Unable to navigate from a "button" tag.

Comment: You can't make ajax request with the component `symfony/dom-crawler`, to test that kind of behaviour it is recommended to use [Panther](https://github.com/symfony/panther).

Comment: I use Panther and I get same error: Unable to navigate from a "button" tag

Answer (score 5):

The `Client#click()` expects only Link.

But you can execute script, e.g. `$client->executeScript("document.querySelector('#js-scroll-down').click()");`